# Full duplex SPI communication with an ADC using the pigpio library

Tags: spi, pigpio, analog-to-digital

I am trying to read the data from an Analog to Digital Converter (ADC), the [ADS1248 from texas instrument](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1248.pdf?ts=1594021338372&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1248%253FHQS%253DTI-null-null-octopart-df-pf-null-wwe) using the [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) in python with the SPI protocol.

When reading the data from the ADC on the MISO line, the manufacturer specified in chapter [*9.5.1.3 Data Input (DIN)* and *9.5.3. RREG*](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1248.pdf?ts=1594021338372&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1248%253FHQS%253DTI-null-null-octopart-df-pf-null-wwe)
that while that the data is sent on the MISO line, the pi should send a 1 on the MOSI line for every bit received.

In other words, it is a full-duplex communication, and the pi, while receiving data on the MISO from the ADC, should send a series of 1 (it is called a NOP command in the datasheet) on the MOSI. See the image below from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1248.pdf?ts=1594021338372&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1248%253FHQS%253DTI-null-null-octopart-df-pf-null-wwe).

[image]

Before testing, I wanted to know if this type of full-duplex communication was supported by the [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open).
Looking at the method: [spi_xfer(handle, **data**)](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_xfer), I understood that method send the  **data** and then catch the response from the selected device.

Is that correct?
In that case, how can I establish this sort of full-duplex communication with the pigpio library?

Thanks in advance,
Rokual

PS: in chapter 9.5.3 the datasheet says: "A no-operation command (NOP) can be used to clock out data from the device without clocking in a command."
So it may not be critical, I am going to try without, but I would like to know if it is possible to do full-duplex with pigpio anyway for future projects :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send 8 NOP bits send a byte containing 0xFF.

`count, rx_data = spi_xfer(handle, [0xff])`

If you want to send 16 NOP bits send two bytes containing 0xFF.

`count, rx_data = spi_xfer(handle, [0xff, 0xff])`

Just send high bits for each NOP bit.

Comment: Yep it worked,
Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Joan's answer worked!
[image]

- in green ==> MISO (data from the ADC)
- in yellow ==> MOSI (data from the pi)

it seems that we are looking at a 24-bit conversion (data rate: 2Mhz) from the ADC (green) and the pi is sending a NOP (yellow) at the same time.

Thanks